# BFS to retrieve elements of values in each order

Tags: python, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I tried to solve the problem [Binary Tree Level Order Traversal - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/)

> Given a binary tree, return the *level order* traversal of its nodes' values. (ie, from left to right, level by level).
>
> For example:
>   Given binary tree `[3,9,20,null,null,15,7]`,
>
> ```py
>     3
>    / \
>   9  20
>     /  \
>    15   7
> ```
>
> return its level order traversal as:
>
> ```py
> [
>   [3],
>   [9,20],
>   [15,7]
> ]
> ```

My solution is intuitive, BFS traverse  and collect the values in each level

```
from collections import deque
class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root):
        if not root: return [] #base case 
        res = []
        #queue to colloct all the nodes
        queue = deque([root]) 

        while queue:
            level_vals = [] #hold the values at the current level.
            for _ in range(len(queue)): #evalute once before execution enter the loop
                cur = queue.popleft()
                if node.left:
                    queue.append(cur.left)
                if node.right:
                    queue.append(cur.right)
                level_vals.append(cur.val)
            res.append(level_vals)
        return res
```

I read such a bfs and queue soltion in Discussion Area

```
# BFS + deque
def levelOrder(self, root):
    res, queue = [], deque([(root, 0)])
    while queue:
        cur, level = queue.popleft()
        if cur:
            if len(res) < level+1:
                res.append([])
            res[level].append(cur.val)
            queue.append((cur.left, level+1))
            queue.append((cur.right, level+1))
    return res
```

I am confused with the condition checking `if len(res) < level+1:   res.append([])`,  and thought it can be '

```
        if cur:
            #if len(res) < level+1:
            res.append([])
            res[level].append(cur.val)
            queue.append((cur.left, level+1))
            queue.append((cur.right, level+1))
    return res
```

Why the condition checking is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition check is there so that a new array (corresponding to a new level) is appended to `res` only when a new level is encountered in the `queue`. Without that check, the code would append a new empty array to `res` for every node encountered in `queue`.

Lets see what happens when you run the code with the condition check. For your example tree, at first the root node with value 3 is popped from the queue. At this time the length of `res` is 0 and `level` is 0 too. So `len(res) > level + 1` is true. So a new empty array gets appended to `res` to store values for tree level 0. The same is the case when the first node of level 1 (with value 9) gets processed. However, after it is processed, when we start processing the second node of level 1 (with value 20), the `res` array has 2 elements (one for each level) and the value of level is 1. `len(res) > level + 1` is false and nothing is inserted to `res`.

Without that check, the res array would be something like this at the end of the iteration:

```py
[
  [3],
  [9, 20],
  [15, 7],
  [],
  []
]
```

Note that, because there are 5 nodes in your tree, a total of 5 arrays are appended to `res` but only the top 3 are occupied because your tree has 3 levels.